# SSIS component DLL Deployment

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-data-flow

I've developed a custom SSIS DataDlow component.

Now it's time to deploy the DLL.
In my work and test environment I've simply registered the DLL in the GAC and coped it into:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents"

and into

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents"

Is there any Best Practice to follow? Is this the best way to install a custom component in SSIS?

TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if it's the best practice, as there doesn't seem to be anything published on this matter. However, that's how I've been doing it for some 5 years now, and it works well 90% of the time. The other 10% are users who installed SQL Server on a drive other than C:. You'll see the same directory structure for both drives, but usually only one of them is in the PATH. You'll want to install to the one pointed to by the PATH.

Unfortunately, there's no reliable registry key that makes this easy to figure out. In addition to the above PATH logic, the installer offers an "I'll select where to install the DLLs" button, it's a useful fallback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was expecting there was a way to allow SSIS developers to get rid of the installation pain, but that's not the case.